# Оцените, пожалуйста, мою верстку

Tags: html5, html, css, вёрстка

http://websterjoy.tk/

Покритикуйте, пожалуйста, верстку. 
Также меня волнует это:

1. Я не уверен что правильно использовал заголовки на сайте, скажите пожалуйста по поводу них.
2. И семантика, хорошая ли? Какие теги html5 я написал не там где нужно, какие можно было бы добавить и куда?

Comment: Валидатор дает "зеленый" - значит все хорошо.

Из html5 лично я нашел только <header> и <footer>, если задача именно html5 подергать -  где <nav>, <article>, <section>, (<aside>, хотя если страница одноколоночная, то не пригодится), <details> ?

Comment: Ну как говориться, валидно - еще не значит качественно)Спасибо.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замечания и вещи которые я бы сделал иначе:

- Зачем вы обернули ссылку с логотипом в лишний див? В вашем случае, его стили можно спокойно применить для самой ссылки.
- В .slider-opacity вместо opacity и background'а можно просто записать цвет фона в формате с прозрачностью. rgba(,,,) или hsla(,,,).
- Не вижу смысла в обёртке для .slider-opacity под названием .border-dotted. С таким же успехом вы можете задать границу прямо в стиле .slider-opacity.
- Не совсем понял для чего вы зачем то вынесли из потока .container. Какая то каша получилась. Если для того чтобы как-то сделать sticky footer  ( добавили ещё одни необязательный див .footer-substrate ), то я бы вам посоветовал лучше сделать его [через псевдоэлемент](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/).
- В меню футера вы используете home только для того чтобы обозначить отступ слева для первого элемента? Если да то, я бы обозначил его через псевдокласс :first-child. Ваш вариант тоже правильный.
- Не увидел смысла в div c классом .feedback. Он лишний. Добавьте этот класс лучше к внутренней форме. Также к ней я бы добавил псевдокласс :after с обнулением ( или .clearfix ) поскольку у submit float: right. Конечно в текущем варианте это никак не скажется, но лучшей все обтекания вовремя запрещать.

> Из html5 лично я нашел только <header> и <footer>, если задача именно html5 подергать - где <nav>, <article>, <section>, (<aside>, хотя если страница одноколоночная, то не пригодится), <details> ?

Внимательнее смотрите, есть там и другие тэги. И зачем тут <details>?

Comment: вариант футера через псевдоэлемент, согласен, лучше, но ведь IE <8 "after" не понимает. А так спасибо, я все учел.

Comment: Пожалуйста, обращайтесь!